# return all columns except one matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose we have matrix **A** like this:

```
   10 5 8 6 2
A=  9 3 5 4 1
   12 5 7 2 6
```

How can I choose a subset of **A** where there is no third column(for example)??
like this:

```
    10 5 6 2
B =  9 3 4 1
    12 5 2 6
```

I know I can say:

```
B = A(:,[1 2 4 5]);
```

but I need a better way

Comment: Please explain,  what are you trying to do,.

Comment: Isn't clear enough my friend?

Comment: And you expect of the better way? I guess your `A` is larger than in the example and you don't want to print all numbers. What about `B = A(:,1:size(A,2)~=3);`?

Comment: @Nemesis Your right It's so larger,There is a problem with your solution: If selected column for delete is the 1st column of **A**?

Comment: No, `B = A(:,1:size(A,2)~=1);` works also.

Comment: @Nemesis It works! Your right.
Post your answer and let me rate it!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative, though not a single line, is to copy over and then remove the bit you don't want by setting it to empty:

```
B = A;
B(:,n) = [];
```

I mention this because in the case that you don't need `B` as a new matrix but just want to take one column out of `A`, this is the simplest/easiest to read way of doing it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
B = A(:,1:size(A,2)~=n);
```

with `n` as selected column (see answer of @freude).

His solution also works fine in any case, but locial indexing (as here) should be faster than his approach.

Answer (score 4):

If we assume that the column to remove is n, it reads:

```
B = A(:,[1:n-1 n+1:end]);
```

Comment: When n=1 or n=end there will be a problem

Comment: No it works, because, e.g., `6:5` for `n=5` and you matrix creates an empty array.

Comment: Not `B` will be empty, just `n+1:end` in `[1:n-1 n+1:end]`. Thus, `1:n-1` remains. Same happens for `n=1` and `1:n-1`.